# A question about the approximation of convex cones

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, convex-geometry, convex-analysis

I have the following question which maybe is too naive.

Let $K$ be a convex cone on $\mathbf{R}^n$. Can we approximate $K$ by a sequence of polyhedral convex cone $K_i$ such that for any compactly supported continuous function $f$, the following holds?:
$$
  \lim_{i\to\infty} \int_{\partial K_i} f(x) dx = \int_{\partial K} f(x) dx
$$
Here the integrals are taken with respect to the restriction of Lebesgue measure on the boundary of $K$ and $K_i$.